# Use Mongoose into a express route file

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm working into a express application with Mongo and I have the following code:

```
import indexRoute from './routes/index';
...
let db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'MongoDB connection error:'));
db.once('open', function() {
   console.log("Connected to MongoDB");
   ...
   app.use('/v1', indexRoute);
   ...
});
```

and `./routes/index.js` is as follows:

```
import express from 'express';
const router = express.Router();
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  // I NEED TO USE MONGOOSE HERE
  ...
  res.json({resp});
});
...
export default router;
```

How can I use Mongoose into `index.js` file previously initialized?

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your imports the wrong way around. Remove the imported routes from the mongoose file. Then export mongoose.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
let db = mongoose.connection;
mongoose.connect(
    'mongodb://localhost:27017/your-db',
    options,
    err => {
      console.log(err);
  },
);

module.exports = mongoose;
```

Then you can import mongoose and use it as expected.

```
import express from 'express';
import connection from './mongoose.js' // Or what ever / wherever the above file is.
const router = express.Router();
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  connection.find({}).then(model => {   // <-- Update to your call of choice.
      res.json({model});
  });
});
export default router;
```

Mozilla have a good tutorial here if you want to learn abit more:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Express_Nodejs/mongoose

Edit

An example file structure could be as follows

```
 - database
     - mongoose_connection.js <-- where top code section goes
 - Router
     - routes.js <-- where you put your router information from second code section
 - index.js <-- Where the entry point to your application is.
```

Then within index you can use

```
import routes from './router/routes'
express.use('/', routes)
```

Comment: Hi Jack! Sorry but I don't understand your answer... My first snippet is my index script for Express. So how I will require into my router my index file? :S

Comment: Firstly I'd definitely recommend you extracting the connection into it's own file so you can import it wherever you'd like.

However in your case you don't need to import it, just replace where I've written `connection.find({})` with  `mongoose.find({})` and you should be good to go!

Comment: I've added an example of how you can split your code to make it easier to manage

Comment: Ok, understood! But If I use multiple times `mongoose_connection.js` importing it, will I make multiple connections to MongoDB?

Comment: Nope, it will share the same connection! If you can't creating multiple schema's however mongoose may make a few more connections.

Comment: No worries. Also I just spotted above I made a mistake I meant to say "if you are creating"!